# removing the \n when extracted the program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a regex for the number of followers on twitter and i have to extract it

```
    # Create a regex for number of followers
    (
    (\s|-)          # first separator
    \d\d            # first 2 digits
    ,               # separator
    \d\d\d          # hundred thousands
    ,               # separator
    \d\d\d          # hundreds
    )
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

## Extract username/followers from this text

```
extractedFollowers = followersRegex.findall(text)

   allFollowers = []
     for followerCount in extractedFollowers:
     allFollowers.append(followerCount[0])
```

but whenever i run it, this appears:

```
['\n90,280,191', '\n84,239,451', '\n79,215,375', '\n75,925,596', '\n62,869,696']
```

How do i remove the \n?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst = ['\n90,280,191', '\n84,239,451', '\n79,215,375', '\n75,925,596', '\n62,869,696']
>>> [i.replace('\n', '') for i in lst]
# ['90,280,191', '84,239,451', '79,215,375', '75,925,596', '62,869,696']
```

If you provide more information about the original strings you are applying the regex to, maybe I could help with the regex part.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this whole python thing and it's for a project basically we have to extract the number of followers and twitter usernames and this is the continuation
# Extract username/followers from this text                        extractedFollowers = followersRegex.findall(text)
extractedUsername = usernameRegex.findall(text)

allFollowers = []
for followerCount in extractedFollowers:
    allFollowers.append(followerCount[0])
    
print (allFollowers)
print (extractedUsername)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` or `lstrip`.

```
>>>lst = ['\n90,280,191', '\n84,239,451', '\n79,215,375', '\n75,925,596', '\n62,869,696']
>>>[i.lstrip('\n') for i in lst]
['90,280,191', '84,239,451', '79,215,375', '75,925,596', '62,869,696']
```